# valgrind - Address ---- is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

First, I know *similar* questions have been asked. However, I'd like to have a more general simple question with really primitive C data types. So here it is.

In  `main.c` I call a function to populate those string:

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    char *host = NULL ;
    char *database ;
    char *collection_name;
    char *filename = ""; 
    char *fields = NULL;
    char *query = NULL;
    ...

    get_options(argc, argv, &host, &database, &collection_name, &filename, 
                &fields, &query, &aggregation);
```

Inside `get_options`:

```
if (*filename == NULL ) {
   *filename = (char*)realloc(*filename, strlen(*collection_name)*sizeof(char)+4);
    strcpy(*filename, *collection_name);
    strcat(*filename, ".tde");  # line 69 
}
```

My program works fine, but then Valgrind tells me I'm doing it wrong:

```
==8608== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8608== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8608== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8608== Command: ./coll2tde -h localhost -d test -c test
==8608== 
==8608== Invalid write of size 1
==8608==    at 0x403BE2: get_options (coll2tde.c:69)
==8608==    by 0x402213: main (coll2tde.c:92)
==8608==  Address 0xa2edd18 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==8608==    at 0x4C28BED: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8608==    by 0x4C28D6F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8608==    by 0x403BBC: get_options (coll2tde.c:67)
==8608==    by 0x402213: main (coll2tde.c:92)
```

Can you explain the error `Address 0xa2edd18 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd`?
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: For what it's worth, I found this error message confusing because I mistook the meaning of "after".  I thought it meant "after the time the block was allocated", but of course it actually means "in the memory following the allocated block".  In other words: `Address 0x... appears immediately (0 bytes) after an alloc'd block of size 8`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`strcpy` adds a null terminator character `'\0'`. You forgot to allocate space for it:

```
*filename = (char*)realloc(*filename, strlen(*collection_name)*sizeof(char)+5);
```

You need to add space for 5 characters: 4 for `".tde"` suffix, and one more for the `'\0'` terminator. Your current code allocates only 4, so the last write is done into the space immediately after the block that you have allocated for the new filename (i.e. 0 bytes after it).

**Note:** Your code has a common problem - it assigns the results of `realloc` directly to a pointer being reallocated. This is fine when `realloc` is successful, but creates a memory leak when it fails. Fixing this error requires storing the result of `realloc` in a separate variable, and checking it for `NULL` before assigning the value back to `*filename`:

```
char *tmp = (char*)realloc(*filename, strlen(*collection_name)*sizeof(char)+5);
if (tmp != NULL) {
    *filename = tmp;
} else {
    // Do something about the failed allocation
}
```

Assigning directly to `*filename` creates a memory leak, because the pointer the `*filename` has been pointing to below would become overwritten on failure, becoming non-recoverable.

Comment: douh! I tried this before, and for some reason I remove it. So I need to be more careful here! But why the vague English?  If my newly created string is larger by 1, why does valgrind say: 0 bytes after ... ?

Comment: Ok, you already saw it coming. So, `0 bytes after` is Valgrind developers way to tell me in plain English: 'It's adjacent', or "directly after it".

Comment: @Oz123: `0 bytes after` is as correct as `42 bytes after`, isn't it?

Comment: @Oz123 Let's say the block starts at 0x8000 and is 8 bytes long. Then the last valid address of the block would be 0x8007, and 0x8008 would be the first invalid address after it. When valgrind sees a write at 0x8008, it reports it as a write to an initial byte of the illegal block as if it were an array of bytes, and it uses zero-based notation to report an offset.

Comment: @Ac3_DeXt3R "Similar" is not specific enough. Ask a new question, and provide all the details.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Yeah, but again it will marked duplicate!

Answer (score 6):

I just had this message because I had changed a class (added a field, so I had changed its size) and not rebuilt all sources that included the header. So some modules still tried to use the old size.

Answer (score 5):

Share what I learned about this issue.

First, the error message is misleading, especially, the word `after`. At the beginning, I thought it means something occurs `after` (in time level) I allocated some memory block. But in fact, it means you are reading data from some random memory address. And that random memory is just `after`(in the address space) the memory block you allocated.

Based on my experience, typically it happens when the index of array is going out of range.

Let's take a look at the following simple demo code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int *x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    x += 3; // x now points to invalid memory(some random location)
    printf("%d\n", *x); // read from an invalid location of memory
    *x = 4;             // write to an invalid location of memory
    free(x - 3);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

which produces the following error message when running the `valgrind` memo check

```
==4720== Invalid read of size 4
==4720==    at 0x1091AC: main (memo2.c:7)
==4720==  Address 0x4a5204c is 8 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==4720==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4720==    by 0x10919E: main (memo2.c:5)
==4720==
0
==4720== Invalid write of size 4
==4720==    at 0x1091C5: main (memo2.c:8)
==4720==  Address 0x4a5204c is 8 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==4720==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4720==    by 0x10919E: main (memo2.c:5)
```