# Heap corruption in my skip list

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

I'm having this problem with my skip list implementation, where I get a heap corruption, when I `return 0;` in my `int main()`. That's atleast where I debugged to, until it crashed.

[image: Debug error]

[image]

This is my code:

skipnode.h

```
template <typename T>
class SkipNode
{
public:
    T data;
    SkipNode<T> **next;
    SkipNode(T d, int level);
    ~SkipNode();
};
```

skipnode.cpp

```
#include "skipnode.h"

template<typename T>
SkipNode<T>::SkipNode(T d, int level)
{
    data = d;
    next = new SkipNode<T>*[level];

    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
        next[i] = 0;
}

template<typename T>
SkipNode<T>::~SkipNode()
{
    delete [] next;
}
```

skiplist.h

```
#include "skipnode.cpp"

#define MAXLEVEL 4

template<typename T>
class SkipList
{
public:
    SkipList();
    ~SkipList();
    int randLvl(int max);
    T search(T);
    void insert(T);
private:
    SkipNode<T> *root; 
};
```

skiplist.cpp

```
#include "skiplist.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

template<typename T>
SkipList<T>::SkipList()
{
    root = new SkipNode<T>(0,MAXLEVEL);
}

template<typename T>
SkipList<T>::~SkipList()
{
    delete root;
}

template<typename T>
int SkipList<T>::randLvl(int max)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    return rand() % max + 1; //+ 1, så værdien ikke bliver 0
}

template<typename T>
void SkipList<T>::insert(T value)
{
    int level = randLvl(MAXLEVEL);

    SkipNode<T> *insertNode = new SkipNode<T>(value,level);
    SkipNode<T> *currentNode = root;

    for (int i = level; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (; currentNode->next[i] != 0; currentNode = currentNode->next[i])
        {
            if (currentNode->next[i]->data > value)
                break;
        }
        if (i <= level)
        {
            insertNode->next[i] = currentNode->next[i];
            currentNode->next[i] = insertNode;
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "skiplist.cpp"

int main()
{
    SkipList<int> SList;
    SList.insert(3);
    return 0;
}
```

I have a theory, that the error could be happening in this line in skiplist.cpp:

```
if (currentNode->next[i]->data > value)
```

because it seems like it can't access next->data, but I don't know why.

Can anyone help me out? And sorry, if I ask the question wrong, I'm kinda new to Stack Overflow. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not to do with the crash, but constantly seeding your RNG with the time will mean that it returns the same number over and over until the time changes, which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: Hmm, it produces different outputs. Maybe I dont quite understand what you mean?

Comment: Are you sure? `time` returns a `time_t` which, on most platforms is the number of seconds since the epoch. You're seeding a pseudo random number generator with that, so it ought to return the same number until the clock changes to the next second.

Comment: Just tested it. Outputs: 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1. Looks like it works :)

Comment: "Works on my PC", meh.

Comment: Would be better, if you could fix my main problem. ;)

Comment: Try using Microsoft's [Application Verifier](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028) to trap the corruption.  It will invoke a debug stop if one is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an [off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) in the for loop in `insert(T)`, it probably should be

`for (int i = level-1; i >= 0; i--)`

Also insert() leaks memory, delete `insertNode`

Answer (score 1):

perhaps try gflags, see this answer :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2476077/3986139

after enabling gflags you can get the exception in VS right at the time of heap corruption instead of the exception after the event